# How can I replace NaN values in DataFrame from another table?

Tags: pandas, join, replace, nan, fillna

I have a DataFrame 'df'

[image]

And the second is 'nan_gdp'

[image]

How can I fill NaN gdp in 'nan_gdp' by using my first DataFrame 'df'.
Also, in the first df I dont have all countries, it means that there are some countries which are in 'nan_gdp' but not in 'df'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by mapped values from `df` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df.set_index('Country')['GDP ($M)']
waste['GDP ($M)'] = waste['GDP ($M)'].fillna(waste['Country'].map(s))
```